# View doesn't appear if displayed in response to a notification but does otherwise

Tags: ios

I have a view I want to display on a certain event. My view controller is listening for a broadcast notification sent by the model and it attempts to display the view when it receives the broadcast.

However the view is not appearing. BUT if I run the exact same view code from elsewhere within the View Controller then it will be displayed. Here's some code from the VC to illustrate:

```
- (void) displayRequestDialog
{
    MyView *view = (MyView*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    view.center = self.view.window.center;
    view.alpha = 1.0;
    [self.view addSubview:view];
}

- (void) requestReceived: (NSNotification*) notification
{
    [self displayRequestDialog];
}
```

When the above code is run the view does not appear. However if I add the call to displayRequestDialog elsewhere, for example to viewDidAppear:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear
{
    [self displayRequestDialog];
}
```

Then it is displayed.

My question therefore obviously is why can I get the view to successfully appear if I call displayRequestDialog from viewDidLoad, but it will not display if called from within requestReceived?

(Note that I am not calling requestReceived prematurely before the view controller / its view has loaded and displayed)

At first I was posting the notification like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: kMyRequestReceived
                                                            object: self
                                                          userInfo: dictionary];
```

Then I tried this:

```
NSNotification *notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:kMyRequestReceived object:self userInfo:dictionary];
    NSNotificationQueue *queue = [NSNotificationQueue defaultQueue];
    [queue enqueueNotification:notification postingStyle:NSPostWhenIdle];
```

Then I tried this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: kMyRequestReceived
                                                        object: self
                                                      userInfo: dictionary];
});
```

Then I tried this:

```
 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(postNotificationOnMainThread:) withObject:dictionary waitUntilDone:NO];

- (void) postNotificationOnMainThread: (NSDictionary*) dict
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: kMyRequestReceived
                                                        object: self
                                                    userInfo: dict];
}
```

And I have tried invoking displayRequestDialog like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
        [self displayRequestDialog];
});
```

---

I have found the cause of the view not displaying - the frame's origin is getting negative values when invoked via the notification code but positive values when invoked otherwise and thus was being displayed off the screen.
No idea why there should be a difference however.

Comment: On what thread are you sending the notification ? Be careful, it's possible that the notification is sent on a bg thread and your UI is called also on a bg thread.

Comment: Try dispatching to the main thread in requestReceived?

Comment: Show how you register the notification.

Comment: @Jack Wu - I tried wrapping the call to displayRequestDialog in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{}) but it had no effect.

Comment: I think it is more reliable to force handling of specific UI notifications on the main thread than to force sending notifications on the main thread

Comment: @voromax - how do I do that? I've already tried calling displayRequestDialog using dispatch_get_main_queue()

Comment: Can we see the code context where the notification is actually being posted? Is it before the view has been loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You are not listening for the notification. Do so like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(displayRequestDialog) name:kMyRequestReceived object:nil];
```

Comment: That is not the problem, the notification is received and the displayRequestDialog method is being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

As far as we cannot see the code you use to register your controller to receive notifications I would recommend you to use the observer registration method which enforce getting notifications on the main thread "for free"

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"Notification" object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    NSLog(@"Handle notification on the main thread");
}];
```

Comment: Thanks, I've found the cause, see my own answer. As to why that is happening I would be very curious to find out.